# Selection of multiple files for analysis in Plotly Python Dashboard

Tags: python-3.x, dropdown, plotly-dash, dashboard

I want to create a dashboard using Python Plotly for data analysis.

Requirement is as below:

1. Multiple files are stored in a folder
2. Inside the dashboard, there should be a dropdown to select one or multiple files from that folder
3. Based on the file or files selected, the data needs to be plotted in a graph
4. There will be second and third dropdown for selecting the columns from which the graph needs to be plotted

I am pretty new to this, don't know where to start from and have not tried anything yet.
Any guidance would be really helpful.

Thankyou.